# How do I copy a SmartArt shape from MS Word with a transparent background?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've created some shapes in MS Word that I want to use on a website. However, the shapes retain a white background when I copy them. Is it possible to copy the shapes without any background color (transparent background)?

The shape is already set to have no fill.

Comment: which version of MS Word are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple.

1. Once your happy with the Smart Art copy it over to PowerPoint.
2. Once pasted in PowerPoint, right click and select `Convert to Shapes`
   [image: PowerPoint <code>Convert To Shapes</code>]
3. Right Click the shape and select `Save as Picture`[image: PowerPoint `Save as Picture']
4. Select `PNG` as the picture type for transparent backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tool called Gimp. Gimp is the open source version of photo shop and can accomplish exactly what you want. I think this would be the easiest and most efficient tool. You definitely need to be introduced to Gimp, it will help you in many ways.

OPTION 2 (due to the comment)

This works for Word 2010. Let me know if you need one for a previous version.

1. Open Word
2. Double click on the picture (This brings up the Picture Tools menu across the top ribbon)
3. Click on the down arrow button to the right of "Color."
4. Click on the button "Set Transparent Color"
5. Click on the color of the picture that you would like to be transparent.

-Good Luck

Comment: I'm actually very familiar with Gimp. The problem is that the image coming off the clipboard has a white background. I'm trying to find a solution where the image has a transparent background so I don't have to try and remove the white background and add transparency to the parts of the shape that are semi transparent via an image editor like Gimp.

Comment: There is one other thing that I remember doing long before I knew of the gimp. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I see how that might work for a picture, but I'm using SmartArt (in Word 2010) which doesn't have the options you mentioned (there is no Color tab).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the symbol, and paste with the option "keep formatting" (which looks like a little paint brush and a lane) then copy again and PASTE at the other program, and it should be the shape only without the white background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to paste the symbol in Paint: Click on {Select} in the menu above. Then click and set to {Transparent Selection}. It should be highlighted and with a checkmark. Then simply paste.

You can add symbols to pictures without that white background. Good for advertising and webpages!

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest and most consistent way
where proper transparency is created directly by Word** (i.e. not by replacing white what ignores pixels on edges, and not by help of PowerPoint)

1. Copy the shape.
2. Paste the shape and from menu in bottom-right corner of the copy select **Picture** paste option:
   [image]
3. Right-click pasted picture and select **S̲ave as Picture...** from context menu.
4. Save the file in **PNG** format.